# Swap Ui-Grid icons with Font-awesome using Unicode

Tags: css, angularjs, unicode, font-awesome, angular-ui-grid

How can I change the font icons used for following class using font Unicode.

ui-grid have following classes as default

```
.ui-grid-icon-plus-squared:before {
content: '\c350';
 }

 .ui-grid-icon-minus-squared:before {
   content: '\c351';
 }
```

default unicode is c350 and c351, I have replaced it with fontawesome unicode like below

```
.ui-grid-icon-plus-squared:before {
content: '\f067';
 }

 .ui-grid-icon-minus-squared:before {
   content: '\f068';
 }
```

and keeping font-awesome font files in ui-grid.css/fonts folder 
it didn't changed the icons, do I need to do some more changes or it does not work like this?

Comment: You need to change the font-family too

Comment: @hans yes, it worked thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `font-family` property to font awasome font, like:

```
 .ui-grid-icon-plus-squared:before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; 
    content: '\f067';
  }
```

Or the font you want.